# How to install pandas in cmd when it keeps giving value error?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, powerbi

I'm trying to install python to use with Power BI Desktop.

I've downloaded the 3.10 version of python and also loaded it in power bi.
[image: power bi loading python image]

Now I opened my CMD and tried to install pandas however it gives me this error as shown below.

```
Collecting pandas
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

What should I do? this is my first time trying to install pandas and I'm having a lot of difficulties

EDIT:

I reinstalled Python 3.7 as mentioned by @seafrog that it was the compatible on with powerbi. Yet however it is causing this issue

```
C:\Users\Administrator>python -m pip install -Iv pandas==1.0.1
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-f6jngabu
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a5eghyrs
Collecting pandas==1.0.1
  1 location(s) to search for versions of pandas:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (4): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (5): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pandas/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))': /simple/pandas/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.0.1 (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 533, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.1
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )'))) - skipping
```

UPDATE 3/7/2022:

I've tried everything since, installed, uninstalled and installed python again, even download visual studio code as an IDE, disabled IPV6 in network settings and (yes I reenabled them again), turn off my proxy under (proxy settings in settings)

I've been trying for an entire week now and I even asked my supervisor regarding this and mentioned it is probably due to a proxy issue however he mentioned that since the programs are downloaded within the same server, it shouldn't prevent me from installing the libraries.

Also to note, they have never installed python with PowerBI before so I'm technically the only one trying to figure it out. this is a work laptop, I'm wondering if I should try to download and install libraries on my home laptop.

Comment: try `python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: @pac same error unfortunately

Comment: have you tried any other python lib like `tqdm` for instance to see if issue comes from your python installation or if it specific issue with `pandas`

Comment: @pac I tried to install other libs but same issue. This is a company laptop as well. maybe that may be causing me some trouble

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images. Always copy/paste them into your question

Comment: I see mostly proxy related error messages. Since you are in a company, talk to the IT department and either have them set up the laptop for you or have them tell you what you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Power BI is currently limited to Python version 3.7.7 according to Microsoft's official documentation (last updated on 04/22/2021):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support

Try downloading Python 3.7 and installing Pandas exact version 1.0.1 according to the picture here:

[Power BI Python limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rn5u.png)

To install a specific Python library, use the command (`-I` will ignore previous versions)

```py
pip install -Iv pandas==1.0.1
```

Comment: you were right, i reinstalled python with the correct version however when i try to install the library it gives me the error above.

Comment: Try without providing the version, like this `pip install pandas`

Comment: Or if you are connected to a proxy or VPN, disconnect from it first, then install the libraries

Comment: have you tried working inside virtual environment ? 
create the virtual env like this `python -m venv venv`. Then activate it, and try to install libs inside this venv. I used to have this issue in a company and that did the job.

Comment: @pac I tried doing the virtual env thing however same problem, kind of at my wits end now.

Comment: you said you are trying on a working laptop. Did it work on any other local machine ? If yes, maybe the solution is to consider building a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay everyone, after a whole week of beating my head because I tried every single solution, it was a very simple task, basically if you are connected to your works internet and it has proxy,
firstly disable the proxy

control panel > network and internet > internet options > connections > lan settings and disable this [proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g6rm.png)

while you're there add 'https://pypi.org.* to the under advanced>exceptions
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhVL0.png)

then go to your internet connections and switch to another connection that is not connected to your company's proxy. (you could try connecting to your homes internet connection)

then simply run pip install pandas.

it should work.

this was a simple solution yes but I had no idea why even after disabling my proxy, it wouldn't budge. I'm still a newbie so I hope this anyone who might come under a similar predicament.

p.s thank you to everyone who commented and helped!